Одовременая запись и чтение файла
Есть поток постоянно пишущий в конец файла. Задача в другом потоке читать этот файл. Можно ли так делать не защищая файл мьютексом? Если нельзя, то какая ошибка может произойти?

Можно, это буквально то чем занимается tail -f
